# How to fix a particular error for a Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Right now when I try to update my Firefox addon by submitting it to the Firefox marketplace so to speak, it gives me the following error: Missing Jetpack module Warning: A Jetpack module listed in harness-options.json could not be found in the add-on. Path: resources/cashbackjournal/lib/handlers.js.js harness-options.json

My question is, how do I fix this?

Comment: Other than the obvious answer that *resources/cashbackjournal/lib/handlers.js.js* does not exist when it is specified as to be included in *harness-options.json* (and the obvious *.js.js* issue), how do you expect us to answer this question when you have not provided the relevant code from your add-on? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) the desired behavior; B) a specific problem or error *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].